# Php problems with if statment inside <td>

Tags: php

I have a problem with my `php` script:

```
echo
'<tr>
    <td>' . $p . '</td>
    <td>' . $status . ' <br /><br />
    if (type == 1)
    <a href="https://www.google.pl/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=lspjV-mCF8OEaIG8ucAP" target="_blank">' . $variable1 . '</a>
    else if (type == 2)
    <a href="https://www.google.pl/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=lspjV-mCF8OEaIG8ucAP"  target="_blank">' . $variable2 . '</a>
    </td>
    <td>            
</tr>';
```

The website address is an example. Does any one know why it doesn't work ?

Comment: You can't just randomly add PHP into a string. My suggestion in this case is to generate the anchor beforehand, and concatenate the result into the echo as you've done with `$p` and `$status`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct way of doing it is :-

```
<?php

echo '<tr><td>' . $p . '</td><td>' . $status . ' <br /><br />';
    if ($type == 1){
       echo '<a href="https://www.google.pl/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=lspjV-mCF8OEaIG8ucAP" target="_blank">' . $variable1 . '</a>';
    }else if ($type == 2){
        echo '<a href="https://www.google.pl/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=lspjV-mCF8OEaIG8ucAP"  target="_blank">' . $variable2 . '</a>';
    }
    echo '</td><td></tr>';
?>
```

Note:- The confusing thing in your code is `type`. I think you forgot to write `$` around it. It must be a variable

So check that at your end and correct . Thanks

For the last question that you asked in comment,try:-

```
echo '<td> <a href="?id=' . $variable4 .'" class="btn btn-default">Sumbit</a></td>';
```

Comment: I have a question, i'd like to add a button in the bottom of the table. I did it by(after echo from last example):

echo '</td><td></tr>';
                        '
      <td>
                            <a href="?id=' . $variable4'" class="btn btn-default">Sumbit</a></td>

But the button is not display in the website.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro ! I am stratring with the PHP and u rly helped me !

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use php code in string.

```
echo
    '<tr>
    <td>' . $p . '</td>
    <td>' . $status . ' <br /><br />';
    if ($type == 1)
        echo '<a href="https://www.google.pl/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=lspjV-mCF8OEaIG8ucAP" target="_blank">' . $variable1 . '</a>';
    else if ($type == 2)
        echo '<a href="https://www.google.pl/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=lspjV-mCF8OEaIG8ucAP"  target="_blank">' . $variable2 . '</a>';
    echo '</td><td></tr>';
```

Comment: `type` ? CHECK ONCE